# Customizing the code given in "Efficient multiclass weighted majority voting implementation in MATLAB"

Tags: matlab

Am trying to customize the code given in "[Efficient multiclass weighted majority voting implementation in MATLAB](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15498368/efficient-multiclass-weighted-majority-voting-implementation-in-matlab)" for use with 4 classifiers while the options remain 3 as they are. The bsxfun returns the error: Non-singleton dimensions of the two input arrays must match each other.How can I match the dimensions of the inputs in this case. How can this code be used with 4 classifiers and 3 options? Any ideas, please help.
The following shows the way am trying to customize it.

```
knn_weight = Accuracy_knn_datasets_overall; % average classification accuracy on the 5 fixed folds

nearest_centroid_weight = Accuracy_centroid_datasets_overall; % average classification accuracy on the 5 fixed folds

bayes_weight = Accuracy_bayes_datasets_overall; % average classification accuracy on the 5 fixed folds

nn_weight = mean([89.5,89.5,94.4,92.3,89.5]); % average of the classification accuracy of the testing sets for 5 iterations

% [knn,nearest_centroid,bayes,nn]; order of the base classifiers

w = [knn_weight nearest_centroid_weight bayes_weight nn_weight]; % weights of the classifiers based on their individual performance.

%% Merging the outputs of the base classifiers to yield a single output


knn_output_3 = knnPredicted_vehicleclass_dataset_3;

nearest_centroid_output_3 = centroidPredicted_vehicleclass_dataset_3;

nn_output_2 = nnPredicted_vehicleclass_dataset_2;

votes = [knn_output_3 nearest_centroid_output_3 bayes_output_3 nn_output_2]; % base classifiers predictions

output = votes;
expression = 'smallvehicle';
replace = 'S';
A = regexprep(output,expression,replace);
output = A;
expression = 'mediumvehicle';
replace = 'M';

A = regexprep(output,expression,replace);

output = A;
expression = 'largevehicle';
replace = 'L';

A = regexprep(output,expression,replace);

B = A(:,1); % outputs of knn
C = A(:,2); % outputs of nearest centroid
D = A(:,3); % outputs of bayes
E = A(:,4) % outputs of nn

A = char(strcat(B,C,D,E)); 

votes = A;

Classlabels = ['S', 'M', 'L']';

%'//Make a cube of the Classlabels that is number of Classlabels by m by n

OPTIONS = repmat(Classlabels, [1, size(w, 2), size(votes, 1)]);

%//Compare the votes (streched to make surface) against a uniform surface of each option

B = bsxfun(@eq, permute(votes, [3 2 1]) ,OPTIONS);

%//Find a weighted sum
W = squeeze(sum(bsxfun(@times, repmat(w, size(Classlabels, 1), 1), B), 2))';

%'//Find the Classlabels with the highest weighted sum
[xx, i] = max(W, [], 2);


output = cellstr(Classlabels(i));

output = output;
expression = 'S';
replace = 'smallvehicle';

A = regexprep(output,expression,replace);

output = A;
expression = 'L';
replace = 'largevehicle';

A = regexprep(output,expression,replace);

output = A;
expression = 'M';
replace = 'mediumvehicle';

Ensemble_output_3 = regexprep(output,expression,replace); % predicted class labels by the Ensemble classifier

Confusionmatrix_dataset_3 = confusionmat(YSML_3,Ensemble_output_3)

Ensmble_Accuracy_dataset_3 = (sum(diag(Confusionmatrix_dataset_3))/sum(sum(Confusionmatrix_dataset_3)))*100
```

The error returned is: Error using bsxfun
Non-singleton dimensions of the two input arrays must match each other.

I have changed it several times, hopefully I have copied it correctly. Kindly assist in customization. For the other weights that are being referenced to, you can give any arbitrary numerical values for code development, if they are necessary. Thank you very much.

Comment: Please post the code (by editing your question) that you have tried and show exactly what inputs you used and where you are getting the error...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that the code you linked to is already general enough to handle different numbers of voters and a different number of classes. If I change *only* the inputs as follows:

```
w=[7 2 6 5];

votes = ['A' 'B' 'B' 'A'
         'C' 'A' 'A' 'B'
         'B' 'B' 'A' 'C'
         'A' 'A' 'C' 'A'];

options = ['A', 'B', 'C']';
```

Then it still works and now is conceptually aggregating 4 classifiers with only 3 classes. i.e. this still works:

```
%//Make a cube of the options that is number of options by m by n
OPTIONS = repmat(options, [1, size(w, 2), size(votes, 1)]);

%//Compare the votes (streched to make surface) against a uniforma surface of each option
B = bsxfun(@eq, permute(votes, [3 2 1]) ,OPTIONS);

%//Find a weighted sum
W = squeeze(sum(bsxfun(@times, repmat(w, size(options, 1), 1), B), 2))'

%'//Find the options with the highest weighted sum
[xx, i] = max(W, [], 2);
options(i)
```

So your errors probably stem from the format of your inputs. Please provide snippets of what your `w`, `options` and `votes` matrices look like before you run the rest of the code?

Comment: Thanks Dan. It was my inputs that were the problem.